# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Total freeze/HangUp

Tags: freeze, ubuntu-gnome, 20.04, lts

I was running 2 Ubuntu 18LTS on 2 separate partitions (sda1, sda2) on the same computer.

sda1 for work. I use it daily, was made with FULL Ubuntu install.

sda2 for personal use. used few times a month. was made with minimal Ubuntu install.

I recently upgraded both of them to 20.04 
- The 20.04 on sda1, has no problems.
- The 20.04 on sda2 was fine after upgrades and updates. I turned it on yesterday, and there was an update, requiring restart. after restart and 5 seconds of use, everything freezes up. I lose access to all the soft tricks to recover. only power/down works.

```
SYSTEM with 500 GB HD: 
AMD phenomII, 4 cores
RAM: 8GB
Graphics: GeForce GTX660
Gnome: 3.36.1 (X11)
```